# How to forcibly inline a single member function in STL?

Tags: c++, stl, inline

After profiling from `perf record`, it showed that [`std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_transfer`](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob_plain;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_list.h) took a lot of time while sorting a list of type `std::list`. Thus, I am wordering whether forcibly inline such member function may increase the overall performance or not.

This is what I've done; change both declaration and implementation in `bits/stl_list.h`

```
void
_M_transfer(_List_node_base* const __first,
            _List_node_base* const __last) _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT;

void
_M_transfer(iterator __position, iterator __first, iterator __last)
{ __position._M_node->_M_transfer(__first._M_node, __last._M_node); }
```

into

```
inline void
_M_transfer(_List_node_base* const __first,
            _List_node_base* const __last) _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT __attribute__((always_inline));

inline void
_M_transfer(iterator __position, iterator __first, iterator __last) __attribute__((always_inline))
{ __position._M_node->_M_transfer(__first._M_node, __last._M_node); }
```

However, `g++-6` failed when compiling, and this is the error message:

```
error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘void std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_transfer(std::__detail::_List_node_base*, std::__detail::_List_node_base*) noexcept’: function body not available
```

How to forcibly inline a single member function in STL correctly?

Comment: Might be worth considering if you could use a `std::vector` instead of a list. They play well with `CPU` caching which can give them advantages over `std::list` even when `std::list` should have better complexity.

Comment: @Galik I am currently working on benchmarking different implementation methods on linked list, so I am wondering what will happen if this member function is actually inlined.

Comment: `_List_node_base::_M_transfer` isn't defined in `bits/stl_list.h`. That's just a function declaration, not a definition (the method is defined elsewhere, like `src/c++98/list.cc`). The compiler can't inline the function without its definition (i.e. body). You could try compiling with link-time optimization enabled, though that's not guaranteed to work (and you'd still have to remove the custom attribute you added to the declaration).

Comment: @Cornstalks After a bit of searching, in `g++` version 6.2.0, there is only a file named [`list.tcc`](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob_plain;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/list.tcc), but `_M_transfer` is not in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [boost::container::list](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost/container/list.html).

It is header-only, so there's no problem to put force inline whereever you like.

Anyway when you need performance, it's not like list is the container of your choice.